# c++ parsing arguments in an exception class

Tags: c++, exception, arguments, throw

I am trying to use a class to throw an exception, the exception though has to be thrown with a value. How can i make the class so that when the exception is thrown it carries a value to the handler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement your own exception class.

```
struct MyException
{
   MyException(int v) : val(v) {};
   int val;
};

...

try 
{
   throw MyException(5);
}
catch ( const MyException& m )
{
   assert( m.val == 5 );
}
```

Comment: thx this is what i was trying to do

Comment: Note: It is recommended to throw by value and catch by reference.

Comment: @MariusBucur: it is also recommend for exception to inherit from `std::exception` and the catch by reference can be extended to `const` reference unless you actually intend to modify the caught exception (and thus in general rethrow it).